# max level in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, is there a way to fully max up your character in all of the skills? Apparently there's the level cap, but I've never been able to find out what it is or how to use it. So if there is an easy way to level my character to the max level please answer.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling#Maximum_Level), the level cap was the maximum level.  However, the level cap was removed in patch 1.09.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling

> At higher levels, levelling up happens much more slowly. Level
>   increases in Skyrim follow a formula. Prior to Patch 1.9 the maximum
>   level was 81, since there was no way to gain any more experience once
>   every skill reached its maximum value of 100.
>
> With Patch 1.9, individual skills can be made "legendary", denoting
>   them with an Imperial symbol. This will reset the skill to 15, and
>   perk points used for that skill may be redistributed. Gaining levels
>   in that skill will affect levelling again, thus effectively removing
>   the level cap of 81.
>
> There is no restriction on the number of times that skills can be made
>   legendary. This change makes it theoretically possible to obtain every
>   single perk in the game. According to the formula, training one
>   individual skill all the way from 15 to 100 (one mastering cycle)
>   yields 4, 930 XP. This amount of XP is enough to level from 1 to 17,
>   or from 194 to 195. Levelling up to 252 (unlocking all perks) would
>   take a total of 809,475 XP. This corresponds to over 164 skill
>   mastering cycles, or mastering every skill over 9 times. The fastest
>   approach to such a huge task would be to find the easiest skill to
>   raise and to exclusively focus on that for levelling purposes.

Regarding a way to level to the maximum easily, I'm afraid I can't help you with that. Maybe somebody else can offer some insight.